# Looking for suggestions on how to arrange 7900+ lines of text in Calc

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc

I have a dataset with the complete text of the Greek *Novum Testamentum* (New Testament); see [an image here](http://www.schulcenter.org/image_uploads/greek_text.jpg).

Each line is one verse.  I will find the book and chapter boundaries with the help of [these statistics](http://catholic-resources.org/Bible/NT-Statistics-Greek.htm).

I want to import this into Calc.  (I love Calc - since it makes it very very easy to search for verses.)  How can I organize the text in Calc to reflect the book/chapter structure of the source document?

Comment: It would probably be easier if you took the text from a source that hadn't already discarded the book/chapter information. What if you have a slightly different edition? The whole system won't work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would insert a column A containing the book name and a column B with the chapter No. Then I would activate the Autofilter function (Data->Filter->Autofilter) and I would format column C (the verse) to wrap text.

With the autofilter set to view all cells, a search will search everything. With only a few chapters or verses visible a search will only search them.

Comment: hello dear W_WHALLEY - many many thanks - great ideas. I will do as adviced.